# Unable to get access token after updating redirect list in google console. "error_description": "Unauthorized", "error": "unauthorized_client"

Tags: oauth, google-api, google-oauth

I'm trying to get `refresh token` which doesn't expire after `24 hours` on google `oauthplayground` but Im getting error as :

```
{
"error_description": "Unauthorized", 
"error": "unauthorized_client"
}
```

I updated my redirect url in google console with https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground.

I also updated my `client id` and `client secret` in configuration setting on google `oauth playground`.

Some posts mentioned that it would take some time but I had done this `12` hours ago but still getting the error.
Any help would be much appreciated.
Below is complete response :

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-length: 68
X-xss-protection: 0
X-content-type-options: nosniff
Transfer-encoding: chunked
Vary: Origin, X-Origin, Referer
Server: scaffolding on HTTPServer2
-content-encoding: gzip
Cache-control: private
Date: Sun, 14 Jul 2019 11:35:13 GMT
X-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
Alt-svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43,39"
Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
{
  "error_description": "Bad Request", 
  "error": "invalid_grant"
}
```

Comment: try following the steps at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766912/how-do-i-authorise-an-app-web-or-installed-without-user-intervention/19766913#19766913

Answer (score 0):

> unauthorized_client

Means that the Client id and or secret you are sending either is invalid (its been deleted) or you copied it wrong from the Google developer console.

Unless you only attend to ever have one user and refresh token for your application you really shouldn't be using developer console to generate tokens.  You should do this with your own application.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer.I have only one console open and the credentials are not deleted i checked now.I was trying to test on playground first before on the web app. If I send it without my client id and secret i get access token but it expires.